# Strange Behaiour with Camel + Groovy + Spring DSL

Tags: java, spring, groovy, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I have the following route:

```
    <camel:camelContext  id="convert">
            <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="restlet:/convert/{id}"/>
            <camel:transform>
                <camel:groovy>
                    request.headers.id
                </camel:groovy>
             </camel:transform>
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

This route should simply return the value passed in the URL as id parameter. 
When I execute this, the first call works. Anything after the first call returns the value passed in the first call. So, if first call is hostname/convert/999, any other call will return 999 no matter what id is passed in the URL. It looks like groovy is doing some stateful thing that I don't understand.

Any thoughts?

The same thing seems to happen with JavaScript.

```
  <camel:camelContext  id="convert">
         <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="restlet:/convert/{id}"/>
             <camel:transform>
                <camel:javaScript>request.headers.get('id')</camel:javaScript>
             </camel:transform>
        </camel:route>
  </camel:camelContext>
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: I used 2.12.1. Now I tried with 2.12.2. Same behavior.

Comment: Can you try Camel 2.11.2 or 2.11.1 etc. We may have a regression in recent releases in groovy.

Comment: Looks like a regression indeed. It works with 2.11.1. But then for some strange reasons restlet does not appear to work with 2.11.1. Maybe the way I use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the groovy issue is a regression bug in Camel. I have logged a ticket to get this fixed in newer release of Camel: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7143

Comment: One last piece of information if it helps. Issue also appears in 2.11.2.